# UI Automator Viewer from SDK tools Revision 21

Tags: android, android-layout

I use **UI Automator Viewer** for various UI adjustments, whenever i am not sure which view is overlapping with whom. Specially when it goes out of Graphical Layout hands i.e. custom and runtime components.

Though i used it mostly for Portrait screens. I couldn't find any way to use in landscape mode as well.
SDK tools Revision 21 release notes are as usual incomplete.

**Any body know how to make it work in Landscape mode ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to see that google fixed it with their SDKTools upgrade. Now i can turn it all around.

Comment: In what version did they fix it?

Comment: I think it was SDK tools 22.3 ! Thought its preferable, update to latest so you can work with recently released features.